# URL rewrite is producing 404

Tags: regex, iis, arr

I'm trying to rewrite **office.domain.com/app1** requests to **server3:81** using the rule below, but I'm getting a 404. I can browse to **server3:81** just fine.

The Failed Request Tracing logs are available [here](http://1drv.ms/1mSEnkJ), but they don't seem to reveal much.

I've also tried `url="http://server3:81/{R:0}"` and `url="http://server3:81/{R:1}"` (not sure why/what the difference is), but both produce the same result (404).

What am I doing wrong in my rule? (Warning: I'm pretty unhandy with RegEx just yet, but I'll do my best to understand your answer. I may have to ask for clarification.)

---

```
<rule name="App1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^app1" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://server3:81/" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things you might want to try, the first would be to change the `regex` pattern to match the entire url you are replacing and capture the part you want to keep. The second suggestion would be to verify that your rewrite url is `http` and not `https`:

**Method One:** (regex change)

```
<rule name="App1" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="^.*/(app1)" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="http://server3:81/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

**Method Two:** (regex + https + port change)

```
<rule name="App1" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="^.*/(app1)" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="https://server3:8080/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

**Method Three:** (regex full url + relative rewrite)

```
<rule name="App1" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="server3:81/app1" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Alas, still no luck. M1) Still 404; M2) No 443 binding on website, only 81; M3) Incoming protocol is HTTPS. I have a redirect rule at the very top to shuffle incoming HTTP over to HTTPS, like [this](https://www.sslshopper.com/iis7-redirect-http-to-https.html). Thus I must keep `url="http://server3:81/"` as indicated (HTTP).

Comment: @InteXX: I looked at your logs and it showed the request url as `https://office.domain.com:443/app1` the url to be replaced as `/app1` and the new one as `http://server3:8080/app1`. You might try match url `(.*/app1)` and rewrite as `http://server3:8080/` or `http://server3:81`. What is the url you are taken to when you get the 404 error?

Comment: Good catch, that 8080. I've got a TFS rule just above it (`<match url="(.*)" /><action type="Rewrite" url="http://server3:8080/{R:0}" />`). I moved it down below this /app1 rule; the 404 went away. Now I'm getting a new error: `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)`. Workin' on that now.

Comment: That last one I'm having trouble tracing; it's an ASP.NET error and so there's no HTTP status code to listen for. It's not looking good...

Comment: The new error is likely related to the path component not liking certain characters ([more info](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mswinswdev/ms_aspnet_server_error_potentially_dangerous_request_path.htm)); if this resolved the `404 Error` then please mark the answer correct, and if you still continue having issues let me know.

Comment: I managed to get it working (somewhat), using this rule: `<rule name="App1" stopProcessing="true"><match url="^app1(.*)" /><action type="Rewrite" url="http://server3:81{R:1}" /></rule>`. Goodness me...  you mean I actually figured out a RegEx. Huh! Will wonders never cease. Now I need to figure out how to handle the redirect from **server3:81** — it's a SharePoint application and it redirects from `/` to `/default.aspx`. CSS, JavaScript and images are all broken too, but so far I'm not able to get past the 500 error when adding an outbound rule. Nevertheless I'll get it...

Comment: +1 for your answer, as well as for your 8080 catch—both of these helped me get as far as I've gotten. Thanks!